# CDN integrity atribute sometimes fails in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cdn, integrity

I use a number of CDN links in my webapplication for javascript and CSS, e.g.:

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-I6F5OKECLVtK/BL+8iSLDEHowSAfUo76ZL9+kGAgTRdiByINKJaqTPH/QVNS1VDb"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Usually everything works fine, but sometimes I get this message in Firebug console:

> None of the "sha256" hashes in the integrity attribute match the content of the subresource.

If that happens, my javascript doesn't load and my application is broken. A simple refresh will resolve that. Rather than getting rid of the CDN links and hosting the files myself, I would like to fix this. Is this a common problem?

Comment: Why don't you use simply : `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"</script>`

Comment: because the integrity attribute allows browsers to check if the loaded file has not been tampered with. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32039568/what-are-the-integrity-and-crossorigin-attribute

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: Thanks, but alas: 
"The hash contained in the integrity attribute could not be decoded."

Comment: The jquery site gives me this: 
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
Seems to work. Maybe it's a cloudflare thing. I'll try to replace all CDN other hosts, using the SHA256 coding

Comment: Yes that's a good things to update your CDN's source.

Comment: Didn't work. Maybe a firefox bug?

Comment: If you open it directly in your web browser that works ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your network connection is working or if you have your browser set up to use Network Proxy that it too is working.

I was seeing this message as I was loading html locally (e.g., File -> Open File) on a browser where the integrity check would fail because I did not have the network proxy (via ssh tunnel) working at the time.   As soon as I resolved my network connectivity, the page would load and these messages would go away (with the assumption, of course, that the integrity attribute values are correct.)

Answer (score 1):

One possible explanation for this is if your system time is sufficiently off. I was running Debian in a VirtualBox instance. I hibernated the host machine a few times without touching the VM again. That's when I noticed certain Web pages weren't loading properly in Firefox within the VM. Once I got here it occurred to me to check the system time. Sure enough it was off by nearly 2 hours. `ntp` was not installed so I installed that package: `sudo aptitude install ntp`. I verified that the date/time was updated with `date`, and then tested Firefox again. The problematic Web pages (including this one) worked.