# Authentication of javascript files

Tags: javascript, security, authentication

I am developping an application for IE 11 (other browsers are not suppoted).
I need to check the integrity of the javascript file (file.js) before execute it.  Is it possible to sing the file, or insure it is the original one that is used ?
Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity

Comment: Why isn't HTTPS good enough?

Comment: What tune do you sing the code too?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32039568/what-are-the-integrity-and-crossorigin-attribute

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTTPS to secure your JavaScript files. HTTPS will ensure that your JavaScript files have not been modified during transmission from server to your browser.