# Bootstrap popper.js Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, bootstrap-4

Using cdn from bootstrap pages causing this error on all my bootstrap pages

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

> Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for
>   resource
>   'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js'
>   with computed SHA-256 integrity
>   'f/3u5OOj9c7fUgL5NEWK2U65jTKCMSzCWp6P+l+eKGI='. The resource has been
>   blocked.

if you are using bootstrap in any of your projects this error might also be visible to you

Comment: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/27645 i had raised this issue here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That appears to be an out dated include snippet for popper.

Currently, the latest Bootstrap documentation shows this to be their popper snippet

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

If you wanted to include the version you have currently listed, you could drop the integrity attribute altogether like so (you can read about what that attribute does here [What are the integrity and crossorigin attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32039568/what-are-the-integrity-and-crossorigin-attributes))

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

It looks like it also may be the case that your browser doesn't support the sha384 hash as a valid digest, so you could also update the digest to one your browser will support like this

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-f/3u5OOj9c7fUgL5NEWK2U65jTKCMSzCWp6P+l+eKGI="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Did you try the second and last approaches? If so, what error messages are you getting?

Comment: Adpt script error [ ti.4070|Cannot read property 'dba' of undefined ] ( TypeError: Cannot read property 'dba' of undefined|z (https://e2b8u3v8.map2.ssl.hwcdn.net/s/965db08d-7bda-47bd-a903-cd2016de2f25.js?cb=19273:3:2757)|B (https://e2b8u3v8.map2.ssl.hwcdn.net/s/965db08d-7bda-47bd-a903-cd2016de2f25.js?cb=19273:3:3605)|https://e2b8u3v8.map2.ssl.hwcdn.net/s/965db08d-7bda-47bd-a903-cd2016de2f25.js?cb=19273:3:8451|https://e2b8u3v8.map2.ssl.hwcdn.net/s/965db08d-7bda-47bd-a903-cd2016de2f25.js?cb=19273:3:33992 ) i don't understant why this is coming with 2nd  & 3rd approach

Comment: It is there for security reasons. It is called SRI. Link to documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity. 

Although we had an issue with not working hashing algorithm sha384 for other OS than macOS. The browser seems to don't have any effect on that

Answer (score 0):

If the above solutions do not work for you, try following steps which worked for me:

1. Visit the Bootstrap website corresponding to your current version.
2. Locate the 'src' field within the script tag and copy the provided URL. For instance:

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

From this script tag, extract and copy the URL: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js

3. Paste the copied URL into your browser, download the file, and replace your existing file if you are using the downloaded dependency. Alternatively, directly replace the script tag in your code with the one provided above.
4. Copy the SHA checksum from the same script tag and use it as the value for the integrity field in your code.

By following these steps, you should be able to resolve the issue you are facing.

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar issue and just ended up removing the integrity tag to every script and link tag.

It solved my problem. I don't think there's much we can do on our end here if we are using CDN service.

Answer (score -2):

Just remove the integrity taggs. Helpt me and it does not change anything on your site.

Comment: This answer suggest the same as a previous answer, also it only suggest hide the error.