# integrity and crossorigin attribute are displaying as not valid in link tag

Tags: css, asp.net

I tried to add integrity and crossorigin attribute to above link, but both were showed as not valid attribute for link tag in Visual Studio 2015. What is the solution for this.

Comment: please show what you have tried

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"> I tried using integrity and crossorigin attribute for the above link, and got as not valid

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Visual Studio is not updating its HTML5-Validator. These are legit parameters increasing the security for viewers of your page. 
Whilst indicating these as invalid parameters, they still get rendered. So you can safely ignore those warnings.

Some background to these parameters can be found here: [What are the integrity and crossorigin attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32039568/what-are-the-integrity-and-crossorigin-attributes)