# dismiss button not close onclick bootstrap

Tags: html, css

Below is the pen where i test this code.But i dont know where is the issues in the code.

Here is the pen link where i put this code.

https://codepen.io/codeslide/pen/xvRomW

Is anyone help with this issue i am new in this but keep try to do better.
The strip is not close when i click the dismiss button.
Thanks for your Suggesstion.

Built in html and css.
**CSS code**

```css
.headerstrip-wrapper {
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.headerstrip-wrapper .headerstrip__banner-dismiss {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  font: inherit;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: inherit;
  opacity: 0.4;
  padding: 0 16px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 100ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 100ms ease;
  transition: all 100ms ease;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.headerstrip-wrapper .headerstrip__banner-dismiss:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
  transform: scale(1.3);
}

.headerstrip-wrapper .headerstrip__banner-dismiss svg {
  fill: #000000;
}

.headerstrip {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, “Segoe UI”, Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, “Helvetica Neue”,sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

.headerstrip .headerstrip-content-background {
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #2930b4; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #2930b4, #2a9eb0); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #2930b4, #2a9eb0); /* Standard syntax */
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.headerstrip .headerstrip-canvas {
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto auto;
}

.headerstrip .headerstrip-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 1000px 50px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  max-width: 1408px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.headerstrip .headerstrip-text {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-right: 24px;
  font-weight: 200;
  letter-spacing: 0.8px;
  position: relative;
}

.headerstrip .headerstrip-text strong {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.headerstrip .headerstrip-cta-container {
  display: flex;
}

.headerstrip .headerstrip-cta {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #FC9F97;
  padding: 5px 30px;
  color: #2d2d2d;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.headerstrip .headerstrip-cta-mobile {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: underline;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.headerstrip .headerstrip-cta-mobile:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}


.headerstrip .is-hidden-desktop .headerstrip-content {
  text-align: center;
}

.headerstrip .is-hidden-desktop .headerstrip-text {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 24px;
}

.headerstrip .is-hidden-desktop .headerstrip__banner-dismiss {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.headerstrip .headerstrip__dismiss-icon {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  fill: #FFFFFF;
  display: inline-block;
}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  .headerstrip .is-hidden-tablet-and-below {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1025px) {
  .headerstrip .is-hidden-desktop {
    display: none !important
  }
}
```

```html
<strong>Html code</strong>

<div class="banner-root">
<div class="banner-container">
<div class="headerstrip-wrapper">

  <button title="dismiss" type="button" class="js-banner__dismiss headerstrip__banner-dismiss">
    <svg class="headerstrip__dismiss-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

      <path d="M19.8 2.4c.3.3.3.8 0 1.1l-6 6c-.3.3-.3.8 0 1.1l6 6c.3.3.3.8 0 1.1l-2.2 2.2c-.3.3-.8.3-1.1 0l-6-6c-.3-.3-.8-.3-1.1 0l-6 6c-.3.3-.8.3-1.1 0L.1 17.7c-.3-.3-.3-.8 0-1.1l6-6c.3-.3.3-.8 0-1.1l-6-6c-.3-.3-.3-.8 0-1.1L2.3.2c.3-.3.8-.3 1.1 0l6 6c.3.3.8.3 1.1 0l6-6c.3-.3.8-.3 1.1 0l2.2 2.2z"></path>
    </svg>
  </button>

  <a class="headerstrip js-banner__link" href="https://market.codeslide.in/">

    <div class="headerstrip-content-background"></div>
    <div class="headerstrip-canvas is-hidden-desktop">

      <div class="headerstrip-content">
        <div class="headerstrip-text">
          Codeslide!
          <span class="js-banner__link headerstrip-cta-mobile" href="https://market.codeslide.in/">From $0.00/m</span>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="headerstrip-canvas is-hidden-tablet-and-below">
      <div class="headerstrip-content">

        <div class="headerstrip-text">
          <strong>Codeslide!</strong> Unlimited plugin, WordPress &amp; web template downloads!
        </div>

        <span class="js-banner__link headerstrip-cta" href="https://market.codeslide.in/">From $0.00/m</span>

      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need javascript to close the banner and you haven't loaded any.

Comment: can you elaborate more.

Comment: Why do you expect the banner to disappear? What makes it do that?

Comment: Its just a offer strip place on header.But if its not disappear it looks odd.Thats why i need to close this.

Comment: I understand why you need it to close. I'm trying to help you learn how to do that. When the button is drawn on the screen, it doesn't know what to do when you click it until you tell it what to do. You'll need to tell it using javascript and the onclick handler. Here's a short tutorial (easy for beginners): https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: I add javascript but still not work check pen link above

Comment: You've got the right idea, but you tried to use jquery and didn't add jquery to your project.

Comment: Try this: add this to the button: ```onclick="dismissBanner()"```. Then create: ```function dismissBanner(){ alert("Clicked")}``` in the javascript. It should work. Once that's done, you can figure out how to fill in the function. Try not to use jquery unless you really have to b/c it will only complicate things for you at this point.

Comment: Btw, if you must, you can add jquery to your project by clicking on Settings --> Javascript, and search for 'jquery' in the CDN box, and adding the jquery dependency. Your function will work if you do that.

Comment: Can you suggest me edit.i mean whatever jquery code is need here.

Comment: Your function worked. You just need to add jquery as I explained in my last comment.

Comment: Yes the function works properly.Is there any way create animation because its disapper immediatly without any effect

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Comment: Thanks @Dov Rine

Comment: I add some javascript and css to the code please check codepen.It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add the below script in your code.

```
var closeButtons = $('.headerstrip__banner-dismiss');
closeButtons.on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

Here is the snippet:

```css
.headerstrip-wrapper {
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.headerstrip-wrapper .headerstrip__banner-dismiss {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  font: inherit;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: inherit;
  opacity: 0.4;
  padding: 0 16px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 100ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 100ms ease;
  transition: all 100ms ease;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.headerstrip-wrapper .headerstrip__banner-dismiss:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
  transform: scale(1.3);
}

.headerstrip-wrapper .headerstrip__banner-dismiss svg {
  fill: #000000;
}

.headerstrip {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, “Segoe UI”, Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, “Helvetica Neue”,sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

.headerstrip .headerstrip-content-background {
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #2930b4; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #2930b4, #2a9eb0); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #2930b4, #2a9eb0); /* Standard syntax */
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.headerstrip .headerstrip-canvas {
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto auto;
}

.headerstrip .headerstrip-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 1000px 50px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  max-width: 1408px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.headerstrip .headerstrip-text {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-right: 24px;
  font-weight: 200;
  letter-spacing: 0.8px;
  position: relative;
}

.headerstrip .headerstrip-text strong {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.headerstrip .headerstrip-cta-container {
  display: flex;
}

.headerstrip .headerstrip-cta {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #FC9F97;
  padding: 5px 30px;
  color: #2d2d2d;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.headerstrip .headerstrip-cta-mobile {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: underline;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.headerstrip .headerstrip-cta-mobile:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}


.headerstrip .is-hidden-desktop .headerstrip-content {
  text-align: center;
}

.headerstrip .is-hidden-desktop .headerstrip-text {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 24px;
}

.headerstrip .is-hidden-desktop .headerstrip__banner-dismiss {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.headerstrip .headerstrip__dismiss-icon {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  fill: #FFFFFF;
  display: inline-block;
}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  .headerstrip .is-hidden-tablet-and-below {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1025px) {
  .headerstrip .is-hidden-desktop {
    display: none !important
  }
}
```

```html
<strong>Html code</strong>

<div class="banner-root">
<div class="banner-container">
<div class="headerstrip-wrapper">

  <button title="dismiss" type="button" class="js-banner__dismiss headerstrip__banner-dismiss">
    <svg class="headerstrip__dismiss-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

      <path d="M19.8 2.4c.3.3.3.8 0 1.1l-6 6c-.3.3-.3.8 0 1.1l6 6c.3.3.3.8 0 1.1l-2.2 2.2c-.3.3-.8.3-1.1 0l-6-6c-.3-.3-.8-.3-1.1 0l-6 6c-.3.3-.8.3-1.1 0L.1 17.7c-.3-.3-.3-.8 0-1.1l6-6c.3-.3.3-.8 0-1.1l-6-6c-.3-.3-.3-.8 0-1.1L2.3.2c.3-.3.8-.3 1.1 0l6 6c.3.3.8.3 1.1 0l6-6c.3-.3.8-.3 1.1 0l2.2 2.2z"></path>
    </svg>
  </button>

  <a class="headerstrip js-banner__link" href="https://market.codeslide.in/">

    <div class="headerstrip-content-background"></div>
    <div class="headerstrip-canvas is-hidden-desktop">

      <div class="headerstrip-content">
        <div class="headerstrip-text">
          Codeslide!
          <span class="js-banner__link headerstrip-cta-mobile" href="https://market.codeslide.in/">From $0.00/m</span>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="headerstrip-canvas is-hidden-tablet-and-below">
      <div class="headerstrip-content">

        <div class="headerstrip-text">
          <strong>Codeslide!</strong> Unlimited plugin, WordPress &amp; web template downloads!
        </div>

        <span class="js-banner__link headerstrip-cta" href="https://market.codeslide.in/">From $0.00/m</span>

      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

</div>
</div>
</div>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
var closeButtons = $('.headerstrip__banner-dismiss');
closeButtons.on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().hide();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks this problem is solved but it disappear immediately without any animation.can you help me solve this.

Comment: Dude why it appear again on page refresh.

Comment: Its look like same behavior compared to the code-pen which you provided. While closing the strip the changes made locally and you are not saving it anywhere. so subsequent page refresh the strip will automatically appear based on how the code written.

Comment: ohk how to get rid of it?

Comment: i Add some code in my pen can you improve it. https://codepen.io/codeslide/pen/xvRomW

Comment: You can store it into a db level respective to the user and its need to be retrieve at application init/ page load. Then you need to make  "headerstrip-canvas" to be hide.

Comment: Thats fine. But local storage is not persistent, sometimes user will be getting the strip again, if browser cache cleared. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948284/how-persistent-is-localstorage

Comment: please find code modification over your latest changes here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PMWwqw

Comment: ohk  its work fine  but only in codepen & fadein not work.Is there any code missing in css.check here am using this strip in  https://codeslide.in/ the strip appear again on page refresh.

Comment: Its seems like working fine in this website https://codeslide.in/ . please cross check with different machine and different browser.

Comment: you can also use .show() instead of .fadeIn(). Both will show the thing , but fadeIn will give some animation.

Comment: Better you can clear you browser cache before testing. good luck

Comment: Thanks alwin Jose you helped me a lot.

Comment: Hey when i use this code at wp header it show [the attribute name of viewbox must be in lowercase] in this line.<svg class="headerstrip__dismiss-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20"  and when i change viewBox to viewbox the dismiss svg icon not appear?

Comment: Here is just a viewBox example can you do change in codepen.I didn't understand.

Comment: **"the attribute name of viewbox must be in lowercase"** is error or warning? If its warning means just lgnore and go ahead. If its error means better you can use font-awesome icons or glyphicans instead of that svg

Comment: when i use fontawesome class the banner strip appear again mean javascript not work.https://codepen.io/codeslide/pen/xvRomW check it why is this happing to me.

Comment: and can u tell me what is this ```integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous">```

Comment: Integrity attribute is to allow the browser to check the file source to ensure that the code is never loaded if the source has been manipulated. You can refer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32039568/what-are-the-integrity-and-crossorigin-attributes

Comment: If font-awesome gives issues then you can go with glyphican which is in build with bootstrap, refer here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/ . Please find the latest code-pen with glyphican https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oKBmPz

Comment: the issue is with localstorage the banner strip appear again on page refresh

Comment: its working fine in this plunker. please have a look into this https://next.plnkr.co/edit/Q5KsiSbYgM2c0yVi . Please check your code with this plunker.  As i said before the local storage will be vanished if we clear cache,etc. This code will work fine unless your localstorage data is cleared.