# Bootstrap isn't working on my laptop but it is on my friends laptop

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```css
body{
 background: url(adam-griffith-sWkkIiTJMYc-unsplash.jpg);
 background-size:cover;
 background-position: center;
 font-family: Lato;
 color:white;
}
html{
 height: 100%;
}


#content{
 text-align:center;
 padding-top: 25%;
 text-shadow: 0px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4), 
     0px 8px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
     0px 18px 23px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
h1{
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 5em;
}
hr{
 width: 400px;
 border-top: 1px solid #f8f8f8;
 border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Purrfect Match</title>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>
<body>

  

 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Purrfect Match</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        
        
        <li><a href="about_index.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="imageGallery.html">Gallery</a>
      </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="online_signup.html">Sign in <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i></a></li>
         </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>




 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div id="content">
     <h1>Purrfect Match</h1>
     <h3>The Only Human-Canine Dating App</h3>
     <hr>
     <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg"  onclick ="window.location.href = 'quiz.html';"><i class="fa fa-paw"></i> Get Started</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I can not seem to make the bootstrap work on my laptop. 
I have already tried to add it locally. 
Here is the code which is linked over the internet through the link. 
I have tried everything. Attaching it in every way possible and it just doesn't make sense as to why it would work on my friends laptop but not on mine. 
I have searched all through google so you guys are my last bet . Please help !

Comment: Does this page load for you? https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: take a look at this Link :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32039568/what-are-the-integrity-and-crossorigin-attributes

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this link:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet" 
integrity="sha256-MfvZlkHCEqatNoGiOXveE8FIwMzZg4W85qfrfIFBfYc= sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
```