# I have a red line under the script tag when linking to jquery

Tags: html, jquery, linker

Trying to link to jquery. My code works but there still is a red line under the script so i dont know what might be wrong

[Here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTjIr.png)

[Here is what it says on the  with red line under](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIeT9.png)

Comment: This might help: [what are integrity and crossorigin attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32039568/what-are-the-integrity-and-crossorigin-attributes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to include jQuery from jQuery CDN: https://code.jquery.com/

Latest jQuery 3 version:

```
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

> The integrity and crossorigin attributes are used for Subresource
> Integrity (SRI) checking. This allows browsers to ensure that
> resources hosted on third-party servers have not been tampered with.
> Use of SRI is recommended as a best-practice, whenever libraries are
> loaded from a third-party source.

I think all is said shortly and clearly and there's no need to add something else.

About integrity attribute of the minified version 3.3.1

```
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```