# Why are my Font Awesome 6.1.1 icons not displaying when loaded?

Tags: html, css

I'm in this course by **[Brad Traversy](https://www.traversymedia.com/)**'s  **[50 Projects 50 Days](https://www.udemy.com/course/50-projects-50-days/)** course. In the **Day 26 - Double Vertical Slider**, the **Font Awesome CDN** he's using is version **5.15.1** which is a really outdated one. I am using version **6.1.1** but my icons are not loading even though I tried to debug it. I want the **arrow-down** and **arrow-up** icons in my **down-button** and **up-button** classes respectively.

Here's my code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>Vertical Slider</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="slider-container">
    <div class="left-slide"></div>
    <div class="right-slide"></div>
    <div class="action-buttons">
      <button class="down-button">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-down"></i>
        </button>
      <button class="up-button">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-down"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3cff899477.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your integrity code was bad. Just replace it with a newly generated link from https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome

**DO NOT REMOVE THE INTEGRITY ATTRIBUTE** See here for a good explanation as to why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49061277/8565010

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

.down-button {
  display: block;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  padding: 2rem;
  margin: 0 auto 1rem auto;
}

.up-button {
  display: block;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  padding: 2rem;
  margin: 0 auto 1rem auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>Vertical Slider</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="slider-container">
    <div class="left-slide"></div>
    <div class="right-slide"></div>
    <div class="action-buttons">
      <button class="down-button">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-down"></i>
        </button>
      <button class="up-button">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-up"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3cff899477.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks bro! I always clicked the "Copy URL" button in cdnjs insted of "Copy Link Tag"

Answer (score 0):

now you don't need download any files from font awesome .
u can use kit
1- visit website.
2- sign in .
3- go to send kit in gmail inbox.
(kit is code javascre)
4-go to html file and pull code in title .
only........

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).