# Why Does Subresource Integrity require CORS?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http, cors, subresource-integrity

I don't understand why my browser allows this:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
```

but not this:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" integrity="..."></script>
```

The latter fails due to CORS. Why do I need google's (or any server's) permission to verify that they haven't changed their script on me? Seems backwards. File integrity should be 100% client side and not involve the server at all.

Comment: You may find guidance in the answers to the similar question, [What are the integrity and crossorigin attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32039568/215552)

Comment: I found some rationale here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/149150/what-attacks-are-mitigated-by-requiring-cors-for-subresource-integrity-verificat but the subresource integrity spec just seems poorly thought out. If the primary use case is to detect changes in CDN resources then why allow the CDN to deny integrity checks. It makes no sense. Seems like a half-baked browser feature. Better off just self-hosting a copy.